# How do I access the a passport js session using an API?

Tags: session, passport.js

I'm making a PERN stack mock e-commerce app. I've got passport js installed with the passport-google-oauth20 strategy and I can successfully log into google. I want to make an API to access the user id so I can then pull up the correct order history from the db, but I'm not sure how to access the session that passport creates.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express sessions, it should create a sessions table in your database. From there you can create an API route that accesses the database and returns the session data.